# How severe is a "10001 layer's data source has a different projection value than the data frame projection" in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.2, layers, distance

I am currently practicing using the generate near tool with some older point shape files and would like to see if I can use it in distance analysis between the points and other shape files like lines and polygons that represent features of interest. When I uploaded the point shape files and the features of interest, all the features are projected close to each other. Since the points and features of interest are all near by each other in the same region in the real world, I assumed that everything was well. However, when I analyze the map, I get a 10001 error of High severity.I am not sure how grave this issue is in my case. From what I read, it may have to do with drawing performance of the layers, but I want to make sure I am not making a mistake.

The data frame properties says the coordinate system is the following:

```
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting: 500000.0
False_Northing: 0.0
Central_Meridian: -99.0
Scale_Factor: 0.9996
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_North_American_1983
  Spheroid: GRS_1980
    Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314140356
    Inverse Flattening: 298.257222101
```

The features all have the same projection, one of the features of interest layer properties says the following:

```
Data Type:  File Geodatabase Feature Class 
Database:   C:\Ento Files\BollWeevilEradication\BollWeevilEradication.gdb
Feature Class:  T2011_LRGV
Feature Type:   Simple
Geometry Type:  Polygon
Coordinates have Z values:  No 
Coordinates have measures:  No 

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

I can see that they both have the same Geographic coordinate system but the 10001 warning has me worried that my distance analysis might end up being wrong.

Comment: The feature class is in a GCS while the map is using a PCS. Use the Project tool to create a new feature class in the map's coordinate system.